# check if vector contains another vector

Tags: r

I want to check whether a vector `y` contains another vector `x`

```
y <- c(0,0,0,NA,NA,0)
x <- c(0,0,0,0)
```

In this case, it should give me `FALSE` because there is no sequence of four NULL in `y`. But if we take a look at vector `y2`, the result should be `TRUE`.

```
y2 <- c(0,0,NA,0,0,0,0)
```

**EDIT**:

I tried to use `%in%` but it seems to only work for elements of vectors, not for whole vectors. The solution doesn't have to be applicable to more general problems. It would be nice if it works for this particular case.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [StackOverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810).

Comment: I don't see why this matters. All I tried didn't give me the expected result. Therefore I'm asking here. What is missing in my question?

Comment: Did you look at either of the links in my previous comment? They discuss why it matters. Also, if you don't show what you tried, it looks like you're simply asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: How general do you want this to be? Because there are probably more efficient answers if the data is only 0s and NAs, or if it is just integers, or if you want exact floating matches.

Comment: I searched on Google for various search terms regarding my question but all I found was  how to use the %in% function which I already know and with which I tried to solve my problem before. I don't want others to do my work, I only wanted to ask if there might be a function or a simple trick I missed. Till now I Thought that providing a working example and describing the problem accurately is enough for a "good" question. Thus, thank you for the links and your comment

Comment: It doesn't have to be general. My vectors only contain NA's and 0.

Comment: Shannon theory is the obvious area to look.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I just want to "improve" my question so it can be looked upon as a "good" one

Comment: X can also contain NA's or X is always 0's only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of `grepl` and `paste`. Here you need to collapse each vector into one character using the `collapse` argument in `paste`.

```
> grepl(paste(x,collapse=";"),paste(y2,collapse=";"))
[1] TRUE
> grepl(paste(x,collapse=";"),paste(y,collapse=";"))
[1] FALSE

> grepl(paste(c(123),collapse=";"),paste(c(12,3),collapse=";"))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Now it works fine for numeric vectors. There may be some rare conflicts with characters, though.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked if it was more than just 0s and NAs and you beat me to the answer! :)

Comment: @dayne Upvoted. I've ended up with the same solution when trying to solve this. You do not need to use `";"`, `collapse=''` is enough.

Comment: @TomasGreif As Ferdinand pointed out in an earlier, now deleted, comment, try `grepl(paste(c(123),collapse=''),paste(c(12,3),collapse=''))`

Comment: @dayne Yes, but you have only 0s and NAs as input, see comment by OP.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
any(apply(embed(y,length(y)-length(x)+1),2,identical,x))
```

Comment: I have to actually go to work now, but I am excited to look at this later. Never would have thought to approach it like this. Love this site!

Answer (score 4):

Just for those who might wonder, a time test of the answers.

```
findit1<-function(x,y) any(apply(embed(y,length(y)-length(x)+1),2,identical,x))
findit2<-function(x,y) grepl(paste(x,collapse=";"),paste(y,collapse=";"))

x<-c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
y<-sample(c(0,1),1e5,replace=TRUE)

Rgames> microbenchmark(findit1(x,y),findit2(x,y))
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 findit1(x, y) 403.79291 449.9028 457.8320 466.4996 603.6573   100
 findit2(x, y)  99.09317 100.7774 101.4513 102.1728 119.8970   100
```

EDIT: 
using eddi's `rle` answer,

```
Rgames> findit3<-function(x,y) sum(length(x) <= rle(y)$lengths[rle(y)$values %in% 0]) 
Rgames> x<-c(0,0,0,0,0)
Rgames> microbenchmark(findit1(x,y),findit2(x,y),findit3(x,y))
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq   median        uq       max neval
 findit1(x, y) 340.63570 383.39450 414.6791 456.38786 532.98017   100
 findit2(x, y)  99.72606 101.11308 101.9399 103.20869 117.91149   100
 findit3(x, y)  23.39226  24.39826  31.8478  35.10592  53.15408   100
```

But in the general case of any sequence in `x` I doubt there's a way to massage `rle` or `seqle` to do this. I'll have to go play with things for a while. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I really like this method:

```r
# Second vector contains all the elements of the first
all(1:10 %in% 1:10)
# [1] TRUE

# Second vector does not contain all elements of the first
all(1:11 %in% 1:10)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I love this.  It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case of 0's only in `x`, just use `rle`:

```
sum(length(x) <= rle(y2)$lengths[rle(y2)$values %in% 0]) > 0
#[1] TRUE
sum(length(x) <= rle(y)$lengths[rle(y)$values %in% 0]) > 0
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: +1 There is base function for everything in R, but it takes years to remember them all :)

Answer (score 1):

The OP didn't ask for this, but here's a way to find where the instances of `x` occur.
 I used "9" as my tagging character on the assumption that "9" never shows up in `y`. Clearly one could choose some other character.

```
 > bar<-gsub(paste(x,collapse=""),'9',paste(y,collapse=""))
 > rab<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(bar,'')))
 > rle(rab==9)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3123] 49 1 49 1 20 1 6 1 78 1 ...
  values : logi [1:3123] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
length(x) == max(nchar(strsplit(paste(y,collapse=''),"NA")[[1]]))
length(x) == max(nchar(strsplit(paste(y2,collapse=''),"NA")[[1]]))
```

I also think there should be smarter way, e.g. utilize somehow `cumsum` (and make it reset to 0 at every occurence of `NA` and then get the maximum and compare it to the length of `x`). After some Internet search I have:

```
length(x) == max(sapply(split(y, replace(cumsum(is.na(y)), is.na(y), -1))[-1],length))
length(x) == max(sapply(split(y2, replace(cumsum(is.na(y2)), is.na(y2), -1))[-1],length))
```

Or maybe to start with `which(is.na(x))` and then somehow calculate the maximum difference between elements in result.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ferdinand's (nice use of `embed()`, BTW), this will return a vector of all matches (empty if none):

`which(sapply(1:(length(y)-length(x)+1), function(z) identical(x, y[z:(z+length(x)-1)])))`